# Format of SQL query results in node.js

Tags: sql, arrays, node.js, sql-server

Using the `mssql` module in node.js, I run a SQL query, but I can't access the results as an array. I've seen that this is done using the mysql module, but I can't find any examples that explain the result format in `mssql`:

```
dbRequest.query('select * from DATABASE', function (err, results) {

        if (err) console.log(err);

        // does not work
        console.log(results[1]);
    });
```

Comment: What if you change it to `console.log(results[1].columnname);`?

Comment: Hello, you can check this web https://www.codediesel.com/nodejs/querying-mysql-with-node-js/ or https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_select.asp. Try with console.log(results)